# Internal static class contains private class. How to create object of private class for unit testing using microsoft fakes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

I searched a lot regarding this issue but did not get any issue same as I'm looking for, finally asking the question.

I'm using microsoft fakes to test the below C# code.

I'm stuck in a situation where I have a below class to test

```
 internal static class IntStaticClass
 {

     //some code

    private class PvtClass
    {
        public string Create(Obj1 o1, Obj2 o2)
        {

        //some code

        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to test create method.

However PrivateObject or PrivateType is not able to find typeof(MyPrivateClass)

Please help me how can I create the object of PvtClass and invoke the method create to test.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a reference to the outer class via `Assembly.GetType()` method, and from there the inner class can be accessed by `Type.GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.NonPublic)`

The least painful way to get a reference to the assembly is `typeof(`some public class in that assembly`).Assembly`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joshua for quick help. Will try this now.

Answer (score 2):

Big ton of thanks to Joshua. Finally solved the issue. Cheers.

I wrote below code to create the instance of inner private class & execute the method of it.

```
            var type = typeof(IntStaticClass);
            var types = type.GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            MethodInfo methodInfo = types[0].GetMethod("Create");
            object classInstance = System.Activator.CreateInstance(types[0], null);
            object[] parametersArray = new object[2] { new Obj1(), new Obj2() };
            var result = methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, parametersArray);
```

Now able to test the method. Cheers.